# Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to override the default animations (actually transitions) in Android, when an Activity comes on screen or goes off as the user presses the Home or Back button. I've tried the ViewFlipper, but that works only on single Activity with multiple views. I'm developing for Android 1.6. Any hint, how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to animate an activity transition when the default back button is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047770/android-how-to-animate-an-activity-transition-when-the-default-back-button-is)

Answer (score 0):

So perhaps you should take a look at: [Android transitions Slide in and Slide Out](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)

It sounds very much like what you want.

Comment: Well I'm not sure that even makes sense. You move between activities with intents so your asking to animate in the intent transition phase...I guess you could call a different 'middle man' activity that runs a 'transition' view and then jump to the real next activity but I am not really sure that is a good idea. I am not sure how to do this and you may not even want to.

Comment: No thats not a good way to do. Actually it is supported in Level 5 APIs by using the `overridePendingTransition` method of Activity class. But I didn't find anyway to do it in Level 4 (Android 1.6).

Comment: @Greenhorn Do you find any solution for animation in api level 4?